# how to show user control from another user control?

Tags: c#, wpf

how to show user control from another user control ??

I Create 2 user Control in the same main window ,and in the load of the main window only the first user control is visible , but i need to show the second user control when i click button in the first user control ??

main window :

```
<local:authentification Margin="0,0,301,191" Visibility="Visible" d:IsHidden="True"/>
<local:recette Margin="0,0,179,80" Visibility="Hidden" d:IsHidden="True" />
```

first user control : authentification 
xaml :

```
<Button x:Name="valider" Content="Button" Margin="658,252,-606,-200" Style="{DynamicResource valider}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Click="valider_Click">
```

code behind :

```
private void valider_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                u = this.e.GR_USER.Single(user => user.NOM == nom.Text && user.MOT_PASS == mot_pass.Password);
                this.Opacity = 0;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Verifer Votre Données " , "Exception Sample", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
            }

        }
```

sorry i cant paste my code because is to long i just need to a simple exp please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to assign a name to the control:

```
<local:recette x:name="recette" Margin="0,0,179,80" Visibility="Hidden" />
```

Then, in the event handler:

```
private void valider_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    recette.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    // Other stuff...
}
```

Comment: the problem is the first user control doesn't see the second :/